# django user creation form required keyerror

Tags: python, django, forms, registration

I made a custom registration form, that inherits from the `UserCreationForm`. However, when you try to submit, with one of the fields empty, i get a `KeyError` on required.
This seems to happen somewhere in the django source code, however I'm pretty sure it comes because of my custom clean method.

Form:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    edit the User Registration form to add an emailfield
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #add custom errormessages
        self.fields['username'].error_messages = {
        'invalid': 'Invalid username'
        }
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirm Password"

    #make sure username is lowered and unique
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        try:
            User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is already in use.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return username

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

The errorlog http://pastebin.com/8Y6Tp7Rw

*Note: I am using django 1.8*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing all of the 'username' field error_messages dict with your own dict. Instead, you should update the error_messages dict with your custom message like so:

```
self.fields['username'].error_messages.update({
    'invalid': 'Invalid username'
})
```

Comment: This indeed removed the key error. Didn't realize that i replaced the all the error messages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have changed the original error messages for the 'username' field (you are not adding, but overriding):

```
#add custom errormessages
self.fields['username'].error_messages = {
    'invalid': 'Invalid username'
}
```

So when you leave the username empty, it failed to find the key 'required'.